# How to implement ondelete cascade in Firebase (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new with Firebase. I want to implement ondelete cascade in Firebase.
Here is the problem for which I want solution
I have two table "users" and "groups".

```
{  "users":{
"user1":{
    "username":"john",
    "full_name":"John Vincent",
    "created_at":"9th Feb 2015",
    "groups":{
        "group1":true,
        "group3":true
    }
    "last_logins":...
},
"user2": ...,
"user3": ...
}"groups": {
 "group1"{
    "group_name":"Administrators",
    "group_description":"Users who can do anything!",
    "no_of_users":2,
    "members":{
        "user1":true,
        "user3":true
    }
  },
 "group2"{
    "group_name":"Moderators",
    "group_description":"Users who can only moderate!",
    "no_of_users":1,
    "members":{
        "user2":true
    }
  }
}
}
```

Please pardon me for above  code indentation.

Now if I removed user1 from users table then how it should be automatically removed from groups table using Firebase.

This can easily done using SQL but I don't know how to do this in Firebase. One way to do this in Firebase is to remove user1 from users and then makes group1 and group3 to null and then in groups table make user1 to null under group1/member but this need 2-3 calls. So is there any another best way to do this.
Please help me I am stuck here.

Answer (score 5):

The Firebase Database has no knowledge of relations between values in its JSON tree. In SQL/relations terms: it doesn't have the concept of foreign keys. This means that it also doesn't have an option to delete related objects with a cascading delete. You will need to delete each value separately.

But you can combine all those deletes into a single call by using [multi-location updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html). If you write `null` to each of the locations for the user, you can delete all of them with one call to `updateChildren()`:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map<String,Object updates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
updates.put("users/user1", null);
updates.put("groups/group1/members/user", null);
// Do a deep-path update
ref.updateChildren(updatedUserData, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
       if (firebaseError != null) {
           System.out.println("Error updating data: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
       }
   }
})
```

With this in place, you could then write [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) that [validate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) that members of a group must also exist under the `/users` node:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "groups":
      "$groupid": {
        "users": {
          "$uid": {
            ".validate": "newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().child('users').hasChild($uid)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The validation rule is a bit easier to understand if you read the multiple `.parent()` calls as `newRoot` (which unfortunately doesn't exist). So in pseudo-code it is:

```
newRoot.child('users').hasChild($uid)
```

In words: a UID can only be a member of a group if it also exists under `/users`.

Comment: The perfect solution which I want. Thank you @Frank van Puffelen